# Prompting User to Enable GPS

Tags: android, google-play-services

Correct me if I am wrong:

1) You cannot programatically turn GPS On/Off on all versions of Android.  Maybe some previous versions, and some hacks, but not on all devices. It simply is not allowed.

This leaves only two options:

1) Use new Google Play Services to prompt user to change these settings.
   One issue with this is what if you just want to allow user to turn on GPS,
   but not WIFI?  The resolver will give them options to turn on both.  How 
   can you just turn on one but not the other?

2) Send user to the settings application by firing off an Intent.

Now with 1) User must have current google play services installed.
If not they can be prompted to install it via standard GPS dialog.

Ok, now for 2) Sending user to settings application. I have the following problem:

When I fire off this intent, they not only get to change the Location/GPS Settings but they can also hit the little back button within Settings app, and adjust all settings. Is there any way to prevent this?  Anyway to bring up the Location/GPS Settings without the inner back button?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You cannot programatically turn GPS On/Off on all versions of Android. Maybe some previous versions, and some hacks, but not on all devices. It simply is not allowed.

Correct, for obvious privacy reasons.

> When I fire off this intent, they not only get to change the GPS Settings but they can also hit the little back button within Settings app, and adjust all settings. Is there any way to prevent this?

No.

Comment: Ok, one last thing.  Is there anyway to use SettingsAPI of play services to just prompt for GPS (even when say WIFI) is turned off. By default, it will prompt for both.  Reason is I'm building a Kiosk app and trying to limit certain access.

Comment: @MuayThai: "Is there anyway to use SettingsAPI of play services to just prompt for GPS (even when say WIFI) is turned off" -- not that I am aware of. "Reason is I'm building a Kiosk app and trying to limit certain access" -- I do not know what a "kiosk app" would be. There are kiosk *devices*, and for those, you just set up GPS as you want by getting to Settings via whatever administrative backdoor you have set up on that device.

Comment: How about pinning the location settings screen?

Comment: @MuayThai: No clue, sorry.